# DevOps Maven deploy artifact: "Failed to transfer file .... with status code 503"

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, devops, azure-artifacts

I linked my DevOps feed to Maven and works fine.
But, with heavy fat jar (180 MB) with a connection that is not so fast (1 MB / s) only the pom is deployed and DevOps responds with 503, when I'm at home using my 1 Gbps connections, it deploys fine.

Is there a time limit to upload artifacts? How can I avoid this problem?

P.S. Uploading also smaller artifacts works fine

Comment: Where is it deployed to ? repository manager like Artifactory, Nexus?

Comment: Yes, on artifacts

Comment: Then I would check the repository manager. Is that used directory or with a proxy in between?

Comment: No proxy, where do i have to look in DevOps? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the repository manager log files?

Comment: Where is it? I can't find it on azure

Comment: I can't reproduce same issue on my side, as I know we don't have such rate limit. And 180 MB is not that big, I once uploads one Universal package with 400+ MB and it succeeds.(In a normal network) Could you please share some detailed steps tso that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Nothing special, just added the azure repository in Pom, i compile with shade plugin.
From maven (intellij tab) i just do "clean" and then "deploy".
It creates the jar, starts deploy, arrive at 180/180 and then gives me the error

Comment: What's the result if you follow steps in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops#set-up-authentication) one by one to do the deploy, same issue?

Comment: That's what i do and always did, but with some artifacts (heavy, 120MB +) i got this error and so my colleagues, but, using a 1 Gbps speed, we don't receive this error.
Using pipeline everything works fine

Comment: According to the description, this issue occurs when the deploy process takes more than 120 seconds? (1MB/s,120+MB) Could you share the full error log when the process failed? And what's the result if you create a new Org, new project, new feed, and deploy one 120+ MB package to the new feed with 1MB/s, same issue?

Comment: Yeah it seems a server timeout error but i reduced the fat jar dimension to 105MB and using a 3 MB/s i got the same error ( and my colleagues too ).
We tested also on another DevOps Org/Prj/Feed and the error is the same.
The error log is just this one:

Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact xx.xxxx:xxx:jar:0.0.0 from/to xxxx_feed (https://xxxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/xxxx/_packaging/xxxx_feed/maven/v1): Transfer failed for https://xxxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/xxxxx/_packaging/xxx_feed/maven/v1/xx/xxx/xxxxx/name.jar 503 Service Unavailable"

Comment: Please create a new org with new project, reproduce same issue there and then share the orgname here. I'm trying to check the response log from background. (I only need the name of the newly created org which is almost empty for test, so that I can protect your presonal data like the name of your company organization)

Comment: Hi Lance, i did what you asked, and that's it:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyLibrary: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.example:MyLibrary:jar:1.0.0 from/to TestArtifactForMSFT (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/TestArtifactForMSFT/_packaging/TestArtifactForMSFT/maven/v1): Transfer failed for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/TestArtifactForMSFT/_packaging/TestArtifactForMSFT/maven/v1/org/example/MyLibrary/1.0.0/MyLibrary-1.0.0.jar 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: You can delete the last comment above now, I've checked all the requests for the test org and test project, there's no response code 503 from azure devops. It seems the 503 is not from devops server side though the error code occurs when deploying to azure artifact...

Answer (score -1):

change your connection timeout variable on maven settings.xml.

take a look at this documantation.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html#Connection_Timeouts